# How does Interlink affect aggro?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Enemies choose to target units based on how much aggro they have. How does aggro work when I combine party members with Interlink? Does the Interlinked form take on the aggro from both units that were merged? How is aggro re-distributed after the Interlink ends?

Comment: This is a good question, and one I've also had... that's going to be a tough one to get some evidence to. Based on what I've seen, *some* tweaking of aggro definitely happens, as I've noticed that if the defender with most aggro interlinks, I see them often lose enemy targeting, for either a short time... or sometimes an extended duration. It'd be interesting to see if this occurrence happens more/less often (or the same) dependent on the role/aggro level of their interlink partner.